# Making asynchronous hooks wait for each other in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, use-effect

I have the following code. I want setArray to only execute when myFunction() has executed. I want myComponent() or at least setArray to wait for myFunction()

Whats the best way to do it?

```
import React from "react"


function myFunction() {
  return [
    //an array of something
  ]
}

export function myComponent() {

  const [myArray, setMyArray] = myFunction()

  return (
        //some HTML where I display myArray
  )
}
```

Comment: I suppose you may use useEffect hook, where myFunction will trigger other hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage Suspense and use never-resolving lazy component to trigger Suspense. See the example below: `myAsyncLoadingFunction` only loads some data after 3 seconds. `MyComponent` uses `Suspend` when data is still missing. `MyComponent` is wrapped in `Suspense`, which has `fallback` displayed when components inside are suspended.

```js
const { Suspense } = React;

const Suspend = React.lazy(() => new Promise(() => {}));

function myAsyncLoadingFunction() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState();
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    setData("Some data");
  }, 3000);
  
  return [data, setData];
}

function MyComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = myAsyncLoadingFunction();
  
  if (!data) {
    return <Suspend />
  }

  return (
    <p>
      MyComponent: {data}
    </p>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback="Loading…">
      <MyComponent />
    </Suspense>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```